# YLMoment not working correctly for anything under an hour ago

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The YLMoment library doesn't display the correct pretty date in relation to the user's local date/time settings. It shows 'an hour ago' for nearly everything, even though I only added the object on the server a second ago.

Answer (score 0):

This was a basic error on my part.

When retrieving an object from your server / API, parse the date using the NSDateFormatter, but ensure it's time zone is set to UTC (assuming that's what it has been set to on your server).

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
dateFormatter.dateFromString(YOUR_SERVER_DATE_STRING)
```

Hope this helps someone, because it had me confused for a while.